# Handling a regression in which the response variable is biased to whole numbers

Tags: regression

I'm attempting to model the time that a person records to do a certain task. Times are recorded in tenths of an hour, so 0.1, 0.4, 1.5, etc.

This 'time recorded' seems approximately exponentially distributed. But I've noticed that there seems to be a bias toward whole number times. It makes sense that a person is more likely to record a round "2 hours" for a task instead of "1.9" or "2.1".

A regression I have tried has low R squared and non-normal residuals. Certainly there may be missing variables from my model, and there may simply be a lot of irreducible variability in the data.

But I'm also concerned that this whole-number bias might be causing problems. It also seems like it might be a common problem whenever humans are recording data, so I thought this community might have some ideas.

So

1. will this make any regressions worse, and
2. are there ways to handle this problem? Should I treat this "time recorded" as a categorical variable instead of continuous, for example? (there will be so many categories that are very closely related though, like "0.2" and "0.3"

Comment: You can use an ordinal regression model (some implementations like `rms::orm()` are specifically designed for many categories) or a [STAR model](doi.org/10.1111/biom.13617), though it might require some modification as it is typically designed for integer data (but can handle heaping).